# Return XML Attribute in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to read in an attribute of an XML object in PHP and cannot get the value.

The XML looks like this:

```
<TransResult>
  <ResultCode tc="5">Failure</ResultCode>
  <ResultInfo>
    <ResultInfoCode tc="200"/>
    <ResultInfoDesc>Product not available</ResultInfoDesc>
```

I've tried:

```
$resultInfoCode=$xml->TransResult->ResultInfo->ResultInfoCode;
$resultInfoCode=$xml->TransResult->ResultInfo->ResultInfoCode['tc'];
```

And several other variations of those but it either returns null or throws an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `TransResult` is the root element and must not be part of the path. Have a look at my example.

Comment: Again, I've tried to oversimplify. 'TransResult' is not the root element - I've left out several layers because they contain proprietary info.

Comment: @user3850146 I have updated my answer with your new xml.

Comment: @The fourth bird Sorry, that did not work.

Comment: You might use xpath: `$item = $xml->xpath('//TransResult/ResultInfo/ResultInfoCode')[0]->attributes()->tc;
echo $item;`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. The general approach you have tried is correct, so if this is not the actual XML and code you are trying, there is no way for us to guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your value is in the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Try it like this:

```
echo $xml->attributes()->tc;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/O47An)

`attributes` returns an object of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) which has a method [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) so you can use echo to return the string content.

**Edit** for your updated data:

You might use xpath:

```
$item = $xml->xpath('//TransResult/ResultInfo/ResultInfoCode')[0]->attributes()->tc;
echo $item;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have this xml tag inside a `SimpleXMLElement` the array notation works for attribute access.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<ResultInfoCode tc="200"/>');
echo (string)$xml['tc'];
```

If `ResultInfoCode` is nested, just use the object access notation and then the array access.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data><ResultInfoCode tc="200"/></data>');
echo (string)$xml->ResultInfoCode['tc'];
```

This should work in all PHP Versions (tested with 5.6 - 7.3). If you get an error or null, you don't have the correct tag selected or there is something else wrong.

In your case, you have to use

```
$resultInfoCode = $xml->ResultInfo->ResultInfoCode['tc'];
```

Comment: Sorry, it is very nested - I omitted most of it for clarity. That backfired! I edit my post to indicate such. $resultCode = $xml->TransResult->ResultCode; returns "Failure" and $resultInfoDesc = $xml->TransResult->ResultInfo->ResultInfoDesc; returns its value. But ResultInfoCode['tc'] does not.

Comment: It does not use SimpleXMLElement - maybe that has something to do with it? It appears to use XMLNS.

Comment: @user3850146 what type has `$xml`? Without that info, it's hard to tell, how you could solve this issue..

Comment: I'm new to this and inherited this project. I'm not sure of the answer to that. $xml = $client->processRequest($params); where $client = new CustomSoapClient and $params = new \SoapVar($xml,XSD_ANYXML);

Comment: A var_dump of `$xml` should tell you the var type

Comment: Oddly enough, var_dump($xml) returned nothing.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing"? var_dump prints always a dump of the var on the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173636/discussion-between-user3850146-and-philipp).